# Sybase Unwired Platform for B2C apps with push notifications

Tags: android, ios, sybase, multiplatform

I have a requirement to develop a B2C application for Android and iOS, an I was asked to use Sybase Unwired Platform.
I found many documents and I read most of them.

But, so far, there's something I'm missing.
On sybase.com, they say: "*Sybase Unwired Platform enables you to embrace mobility across your entire organization*". Looks like that SUP is only suitable for enterprise applications, not for B2C apps (for the end user).

I understand there's an IDE (Sybase Unwired Workspace) which is basically eclipse-java, but they also say that's possible to develop multi-platform applications. How exactly is that requirement fulfilled? Does it do a cross-compile or something like that? Does it use HTML5+CSS+JS like PhoneGap?
It is possible to support push notifications?

Answer (score 2):

You can design a diagram of MBOs in Sybase Unwired Workspace. This diagram has two purposes:

- To be deployed to a server
- To generate code

Code can be generated for multiple platforms[0]. See Sybase's entry about [Object API Code Generation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01781.0213/doc/html/mqu1257380014692.html).

You can also find *Developer Guide*s in Sybase's online docs. There are little tutorials to create sample applications for different platforms.

[0] BlackBerry and Android (Java), iOS (Objective-C), Windows Mobile and Windows (C#)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on Windows Mobile app to work with SUP to interface customer's back-end system. As far as I know, current SUP supports MBS(Message based synchronization) only for iOS. For other devices, RBS(Replication based sync) can be used. Basically SUP allows developers to design MBO(Mobile business object) to wrap the required business logic and to generated code that, in turn, can be used in device app development. Bob

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be full filled in two ways. One is by developing hybrid web container app using the sybase unwired platform(These apps are used for decision making), which needs zero coding(You can customize the app using javascript,html5 and css).

The other approach is developing native apps for android and ios. It needs designing of MBO's in sybase unwired platform and deivice(JAVA-android, Objective c-ios).